# How do I send an auto response to a partner trying to email the Jira Service Desk?

Tags: jira

I need to prevent partners from opening tickets by emailing our Service Desk. Instead we need an auto response informing them to please go to the applicable URL.

I tried Jira Email This Issue but it doesn't seem to have anything for this function.

Comment: Hello Ken, please share the more details with the specific problem so that you may get the solution

Comment: I need an email to go out to anyone who sends an email to our service desk stating that they need to go to their partner url and submit a ticket from partner portal. When I set up the mail handlers it sends this message to both the users who submit a ticket via the portal and nothing goes to the person who tried to send ticket as an email.